# How to use JQuery and custom site variables with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I'm trying out phantomjs for browser testing and am having a few issues. My current code is below...

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://address.com', function(){
    console.log('page opened');
        page.evaluate(function(){
            console.log('inside page eval');
            varname.varaction(13633);
        })
        if (jQuery('#bcx_13633_iframe_overlay').is(':visible')){
            console.log('it is visible');
        } else {
            console.log('it is not visible');
        }
        console.log('made it to exit');
    phantom.exit();
})
```

I've tried using includeJS with a link to jQuery and wrapping that around everything between page.open and phantom.exit but it seems to stall out and skip that portion. I have custom actions located on the site that I can call in the console if i visit it as called in the code listed above, however, it tells me that it can't find the variable name for that either. Anyone with phantomjs experience have any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: You should try to use something that has wrapped phantomjs specifically for testing. I am a fan of [zuul](https://npmjs.org/package/zuul) for several reasons (mostly it can do phantomjs AND real browsers too)

Comment: the right way to do it is to include jquery, so if that's not working, you should figure out why that's the case.